# Regular expression for "Every word beings with the same letter"

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to check that every word of some input begins with the same letter (and also allows certain punctuation).

Currently I have the following:

```
^(((\b[aA])\w*([\s\.\-\!\?\"\':,])*)+)|(((\b[bB])\w*([\s\.\-\!\?\"\':,])*)+)$
```

Going from [aA] all the way up to [zZ]

Obviously this isn't the nicest way to go about it.
Does anyone have a smart regular expression?

Thanks.

Comment: do you really want to do it with regex? seem sort of cannon for mosquito -- and i dont even know if it is possible to do such checking, depending on the language being used

Comment: Why not just capture all the beginning letters, and check in your application whether they are all the same? Seems fast & maintainable.

Comment: This is for a website for stories with different rules. In order to keep everything as generic as possible, I'm storing rules in the database as regular expressions. But you're right, would have been easier to do it in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backreferences with case-insensitive matching.

```
^\s*([a-z])[a-z]*(?:\s+\1[a-z]*)*\s*$
```

Comment: Don't you mean something like `^\s*([a-z])[a-z]*((?:\s+\1[a-z]*)\s*)*$`?

Comment: doesnt this apply for only one line?

Comment: @NullUserException - Oops, yes; well, sorta. The `\s+` is already covered. Thanks, edited my solution.

Comment: @Rubens - Hm, it should cover multiple lines, since `\s` matches `\r\n\t\f`.